# How can I get symbols to appear in the middle of commutative diagrams using tikz-cd?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I'd like to get question mark symbols in the centre of my commutative diagrams, thus:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
A \arrow{d}[swap]{\beta} & K_h \arrow{l}[swap]{\pi'} \arrow{d}[swap]{\gamma} \arrow{r}{\pi} & A \arrow{d}{\alpha} & & \\
F(A) & F(K_h) \arrow{l}{F(\pi')} \arrow{r}[swap]{F(\pi)} & F(A) & \hspace{-14em}\raisebox{2.25em}{?} & \hspace{-32em}\raisebox{2.25em}{?}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

What I've done here is a hack to show you what I mean, it doesn't work for more complex diagrams. I guess some kind of absolute positioning functionality would do, but I can't unearth it. I'm happy with tikz-cd and don't want to switch to another package. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use a `description` arrow with `draw=none`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd,
mysymbol/.style={start anchor=center,end anchor=center,draw=none}
}
\newcommand\MySymb[2][?]{%
  \arrow[mysymbol]{#2}[description]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \MySymb{dr}\arrow{d}[swap]{\beta} & K_h \MySymb{dr}\arrow{l}[swap]{\pi'} \arrow{d}[swap]{\gamma} \arrow{r}{\pi} & A \arrow{d}{\alpha} & & \\
F(A) & F(K_h) \arrow{l}{F(\pi')} \arrow{r}[swap]{F(\pi)} & F(A) & \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new style was defined using `start anchor=center,end anchor=center,draw=none` options (thanks to **Qrrbrbirlbel** for this suggestion); this style was used for the command `\MySymb` which uses a `description` arrow, and has one mandatory argument for the arrow direction specification and one optional argument for the symbol to be used (default symbol=`?`).

Comment: For node sizes that differ very much, it may be better to also use `start anchor=center, end anchor=center` (which should be `/.style`d with `draw=none` and `description` for easier access) so that the `?` lie in the center between the nodes.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I've updated my answer incorporating your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry it's taken me several years to get around to accepting this your answer! Many, many thanks.

Comment: What if the diagram is triangular?